# I wrote an ATM Python code and it shows a syntax error that says " 'break' outside of loop "

Tags: python

```
import random

balance = random.randint(100,1000)
attempts = 3

print('**Welcome To My ATM**')

while attempts > 3:
    pin = input('Pleas enter your 4-digit PIN: ')
    if pin == '0000':
        print('CORRECT PIN')
        break
    else:
        attempts-= 1
        print('INCORRECT PIN. You have ',attempts,' attempt/s left, try again.')
if attempts == 0:
    print('You have exceeded your attempts limit.')
    print('Please take your card')
else:
    while True:
        print('1: Check Balance')
        print('2: Deposit')
        print('3: Withdraw')
        print('4: Exit')
    choose = int(input('Choose which service you want from 1 to 4: '))
    if choose == 1:
        print('Your current balance is', balance)
    elif choose == 2:
        amount1 = int(input('Please enter the amount you want to deposit: '))
        balance+= amount1
        print('Your new balance will be displayed in a moment...')
        print(balance)
    elif choose == 3:
        amount2 = int(input('Please enter the amount you want to withdraw: '))
        if balance >= amount2:
            balance-= amount2
            print('Cash is will be out any moment...')
            print('Your new balance is ', balance)
        else:
            print('Sorry, insufficient funds. Current balance is ',balance)
    elif choose == 4:
        print('Thank you for using this ATM.')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid choice, please try again')
```

The break function after elif choose == 4 is the one that displays as 'outside of loop' when I run this code.

I don't understand why, the first break function I used was okay and I used this one in the same way but for some reason, it doesn't work. I checked my indentations and everything but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Post the full traceback message. That makes it easier to see the failing line.

Comment: `choose = int(input('Choose which service you want from 1 to 4: '))`and following are not in the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Your indenting is wrong. The "break" on line 43 is outside of the scope of the while loop on line 20.

To fix this, indent everything after line 25, this will place everything inside of the scope so you can break out of the loop if you need it.

```py
import random

balance = random.randint(100,1000)
attempts = 3

print('**Welcome To My ATM**')

while attempts > 3:
    pin = input('Pleas enter your 4-digit PIN: ')
    if pin == '0000':
        print('CORRECT PIN')
        break
    else:
        attempts-= 1
        print('INCORRECT PIN. You have ',attempts,' attempt/s left, try again.')
if attempts == 0:
    print('You have exceeded your attempts limit.')
    print('Please take your card')
else:
    while True:
        print('1: Check Balance')
        print('2: Deposit')
        print('3: Withdraw')
        print('4: Exit')
        choose = int(input('Choose which service you want from 1 to 4: '))
        if choose == 1:
            print('Your current balance is', balance)
        elif choose == 2:
            amount1 = int(input('Please enter the amount you want to deposit: '))
            balance+= amount1
            print('Your new balance will be displayed in a moment...')
            print(balance)
        elif choose == 3:
            amount2 = int(input('Please enter the amount you want to withdraw: '))
            if balance >= amount2:
                balance-= amount2
                print('Cash is will be out any moment...')
                print('Your new balance is ', balance)
            else:
                print('Sorry, insufficient funds. Current balance is ',balance)
        elif choose == 4:
            print('Thank you for using this ATM.')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid choice, please try again')
```